# Sort Column with matching string

Tags: sed, awk

I have tab-demlimted file, I want to sort them only for red_ball as follows

input.txt

```
id      tagid    name
HH556   EN76     red_ball
JH678   EN45     green_ball
MH678   CV67     red_ball
TY896   RT56     red_ball
```

output.txt

```
Red_ball

id  tagid
HH556   EN76
MH678   CV67
TY896   RT56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  printf 'Red_ball\nid\ttagid\n\n'
  awk -F'\t'  'NR>1 && $3 == "red_ball" {print $1 "\t" $2}' < input.txt |
    sort
} > output.txt
```